# Как ускорить сайт на котором 10мб оптимизированной графики?

Tags: php, графика, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть простой одностраничный php сайт. На нем очень большое количество графики (10мб). Вся графика сжата максимально, то есть уменьшить ее размер уже не получится. Но сайт грузится медленно и просто прелоудер тут не поможет.

Есть ли способы ускорить сайт? Возможно как-то выстроить поочередность загрузки картинок, или еще что-то...

Буду очень благодарен за совет!

Comment: Ленивая подгрузка данных через js

Comment: мб какую то графику можно заменить на css, svg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать отложенную загрузку изображений например с помощью https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/ (условно говоря загружать по 10-20 картинок, а остальное подгружать если пользователь прокручивает страницу вниз)